# Odds for AAAKK Full House in Flop with 8 Players

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds, full-house

Today we have a casual game with 8 people (including me), and in table was Full House with AAAKK.

What are the odds for this flop?

also, have you seen this in recorded games?

Comment: Do you mean only one of the players had this hand (2 hole cards + 3 on the flop), or that this was on the table after all five cards came out?

Comment: @BowlOfRed it was on the table after all five cards came out... Isn't just amazing?